# How do you initialize a static member of an inaccessible template class?

Tags: c++, templates, clang

I have code similar to the following, where a class template has a static variable that needs to be initialized. I then have a template class typedef that uses a private, inner class as the template argument:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo
{
private:
  static const char* s_name;
};

class Bar
{
private:
  class Baz
  {
  // ...
  };

  typedef Foo<Baz> FooBaz;
};
```

I thought I could initialize the static variable like this:

```
template<>
const char* Foo<Bar::Baz>::s_name = "foobaz";
```

And it works... in MS Visual Studio 2015. However, when I build with clang, I get the an error like the following:

```
Error 'Baz' is a protected member of 'Bar'
```

Why does this work with MSVS, but not clang? Is there a way to initialize this variable that will work with both?

Comment: Simple, make `Baz` a `public` name inside `Bar`

Comment: GCC also complains.  I'm quite sure MSVC is wrong and this code should not compile.

Comment: MSVC is buggy here. Using *any* name from a class is supposed to go through *member access* checks

Answer (score 0):

Make a "typedef Foo FooBaz" public in "Bar" and use "Bar::FooBaz::s_name".

Comment: It's only used internally to Bar, and shouldn't be part of the public interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use that, if you do not care about partial instantiation.

```
template<typename T>
   const char *  Foo<T>::s_name = "foo";
```

for partials you need to make Foo a friend to Bar.

```
class Bar
{
private:
    class Baz {
       // ...
    };
    friend class Foo<Baz>;

    typedef Foo<Baz> FooBaz;

};
template<>
    const char * Foo<Bar::Baz>::s_name = "barbaz";
```